# Will my files be deleted if the Azure webapp is upgraded or updated by Microsoft?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If I have an Azure web app which has to download a file from Azure storage, save it to a folder then process it.

If the Azure web app is upgraded/ updated by Microsoft, will my saved file be lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you write the files under the %HOME% folder, they will be persisted regardless of upgrades performed by Microsoft. Only you can ever modify those files.

See [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) for more details.